# Paginate array in a document mongodb aggregation

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

I have users collection and each document has sub-document (followed/followers) and I want to create API for getting followers of user

This query is working fine but am trying to make a paginate results to get for example 10 results per page

```
{
        $match: { username: new RegExp(username, "i") }
      },
      {
        $unwind: "$followers"
      },
      {
        $lookup: {
          from: "users",
          localField: "followers",
          foreignField: "_id",
          as: "info"
        }
      },
      {
        $unwind: "$info"
      },
      {
        $project: {
          info: {
            _id: 1,
            username: 1,
            avatar: { $ifNull: ["$info.avatar", ""] },
            fullname: { $ifNull: ["$info.fullname", ""] },
            follow_status: {
              $cond: [{ $in: ["$info._id", "$followed"] }, 1, 0]
            }
          }
        }
      },
      {
        $replaceRoot: { newRoot: "$info" }
      }
```

Apprecating your support

**Solution**

I used https://github.com/NetanelBasal/paginate-array library to paginate the array after aggregation stage.

Comment: You basically need operators like `$bucket` or `$bucketAuto`

Comment: appreciated for an example :)

Answer (score 0):

https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongoose-paginate This plugin library is what I use to paginate all my API calls that require it, it can be super basic or super complex and easy to plug into front-end aswell

Comment: I used this for the whole collection, but what if I need to paginate a sub-document?

Comment: I believe you can parse the populate, or do another query after getting the populate that gives out desired results, ill see if i have an example

Comment: Yes please if you have an example

Comment: I looked through and I couldnt find any but couldnt you just populate when someone calls that particular one, i think i might have miss understood the scope of your problem

Comment: Resolved, thanks a lot the solution was paginating the array after aggregation

Comment: :D glad you got it working, you should edit your post w/ the solution or post the solution as the answer

Comment: Added the solution in the post, Thanks @Cacoon